# Creating folder in maven project under the src/test/resources

Tags: eclipse, maven, maven-plugin

I am trying to create one folder under src/test/resources but i am not getting proper folder

getting like below screen shot

[image]

but i need like below image

[image]

Comment: In addition to the `src/test/resource` folder there should be the folder `src` which you can use instead to navigate to your subsubsubfolder.

Answer (score 0):

There is no difference between the two folders , it dependes to eclipse perspective , but if you want show folder icon and not sources icon you can simply change the name from `config` to `config-project` like this :

[image]

Comment: I have renamed the folder with hypen, but its showing config-xxxx is not valid identifier

Comment: I have given both screenshots from same eclipse but projects are different

Comment: wich perspective you use in eclipse?

Comment: try to create new one and not rename it

Answer (score 0):

Right click on the project. Select properties. Go to Java Build path.

Select source tab. There you'll get an entry for src/test/resources. Expand that node, this will show following nodes:

[image]

Double click on excluded. Add exclusion patters as I have added *testInput*:
[image]

In your case it'll be config. press Finish ->Ok. This will make your eclipse to treat config as non source folder.